# Different solution for dy/dx ?!?!

Tags: calculus

When I searched for the value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for the equation $y^2 = -\frac{1}{x^2}$, I found the answer given as $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x^3 y}$. However, searching for the value of $\frac{dy}{dx}$ for the equation $x^2 y^2 = -1$ instead gave $\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{y}{x}$.
I have just started calculus and I am not sure which is more appropriate as both the equation are essentially the same.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

Your equation is $x^2y^2 = -1$. We may use this equation to show that these two answers are the same:
$$\frac{1}{x^3 y} = \frac{1}{x^2y^2}\cdot \frac{y}{x} = -\frac{y}{x}.$$

Comment: REALLY thanks!
I was confused for so long and yet the answer was so simple

Comment: @hAl0o0 I'm glad I could help! Feel free to accept my answer if you felt it was useful for you :)